# TomEE Plus and JPA

Tags: jpa

I am trying to set up JPA in my TomEE Plus. I have got my persistence.xml as below

```
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDB</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.TestEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

When i deploy my App, i can't see any errors in the console. I can also see the logs which binds the PU to the JNDI.

But no tables are created in the DB.

Can some please help me in this?

Comment: Why do you have two `<persistence-unit>` nested in each other?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

If `<provider>` is not specified in the   `persistence.xml` ,then the container will use its default persistence provider .For TomEE ,its default persistence provider is OpenJPA.

The `<properties>` should match the persistence provider you are using .

So , if you are using  OpenJPA , your  `persistence.xml`  should look like this: (OpenJPA 's `<properties>`  can be found at [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.1.1/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_conf_jdbc.html))

```
 <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.TestEntity</class>
     <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mysql"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

If you want to use hibernate as the persistence provider , your  `persistence.xml`  should look like this:

```
 <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDB</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.TestEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I don't think that's required. JPA 2.0 spec: "The provider element is **optional**, but should be specified if the application is dependent upon a particular persistence provider being used."

Comment: Because the `persistence.xml` posted by the OP contains hibernate specified properties, so i guess he is using hibernate as the persistence provider

Comment: I understood it as something like: the container will provide you with its default JPA provider, but if you want some specific (i.e. EclipseLink in this case) than define it in `<provider>`. What do you think Ken?

Comment: @Piotr Nowicki  : I think you are right . It seems that if the `<provider>` is not specified ,then the container will pick up its default persistence provider . It is verified in this : `http://openejb.apache.org/openjpa.html` . If no `<provider>` is specified , then TomEE will use its default persistence provider ,which is OpenJPA.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I could not get it working with Hibernate. I did mention the provider as hibernate and also added all the jars to Catlina_home/lib. It doesn't give any excpetions but still doesn't create any entities.

Comment: It doesn't create entities or doesn't create tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default JPA implementation shipped with TomEE (OpenJPA) rather than Hibernate, you should:

```
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
```